# How to authenticate user on server with firebase when they are already authenticated on client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an angular app that uses firebase to authenticate users on the client.  This seems to work properly.

```
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private af_auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user$ = this.af_auth.authState;
    this.user$.subscribe(user => {
      // do something with the firebase user
    });
  }

}
```

I also have some server-based stuff running in node.js with express.  I would like to try to verify that the user hitting my endpoint is already authenticated with my app through firebase.  Can I do this?

I'd like to have a route handler in express something like this:

```
var firebase_app = firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config); 

auth.isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {

    // I had seen a suggestion to do the following, but currentUser is always null here.
    var user = firebase_app.auth().currentUser;

    if (user !== null) {
        // Authenticated with my app?
        req.auth_user = user;
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(401).send({error: 'Nope'});
    }
};
```

How can I tell from within the express route handler that my user is logged in to my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 Angular. Send the Firebase Auth ID token in the header from angular to your express endpoint.

```js
 postRequest() {
    const url = 'https://your-endpoint';
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then(authToken => {
              const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken });
              return this.http.post(url, { someData } , { headers }).toPromise()
            })
    }
```

Step 2 Node. Decrypt the the auth token using the Firebase admin SDK. `verifyIdToken` verifies the Firebase ID token (JWT). If the token is valid, the promise is fulfilled with the token's decoded claims; otherwise, the promise is rejected.

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(yourConfig);
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.post('/your-endpoint', (req, res) => {

  const token = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]

  return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
              .then(decodedToken => {
                  const uid = decodedToken.uid;
                  res.status(200).send('Looks good!')

              })
              .catch(err => res.status(403).send('Unauthorized'))


});
```

Sources:

https://jwt.io/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/secure-firebase-cloud-functions/

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!